# Brand logo after login

Tags: unity, login, screen, login-screen, logo

I changed my desktop to Ubuntu Mate and came back to Ubuntu default desktop. Now after entering my password I see my laptop brand logo for a few seconds. After that Ubuntu starts normally so is not a real problem. Anyway I would like to know why this happens so if you can give me a hint to understand what is going on I will really aprecciate that.

Comment: ***Now after entering my password I see my laptop brand logo for a few seconds.:*** Are you talking about the system password or OS's password?

Comment: I mean to the OS's password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes)

> Ubuntu Desktop
>
> - New graphical boot splash (integrates with the system BIOS logo).

This means it shows the vendor's logo while booting.

Further Reading: [Ubuntu 20.04 Download Link & Top Features (Updated) - OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-20-04-release-features)

> And, in keeping with other Linux distros, Focal now shows your
>   computer’s OEM logo on the boot splash in an effort to deliver a
>   ‘flicker free’ boot experience:

Comment: Yes, it is a new feature that is now enabled by default and supposed to create a flicker-free boot experience. See also [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/03/ubuntu-20-04-oem-boot-splash)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue and after several minutes validating, let me gift you here the solution.

You should restore the gnome config again:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

It happens when you use other desktop environment and go back, the other update the same OEM's logo according to your BIOS.