# Manufacture logo shown instead of the login screen when booted with an external monitor

Tags: boot, login-screen, ubuntu-mate, lid

Background: I have always been frustrated with the way Ubuntu handles laptop's lid behaviour while connected to an external monitor. This was also an issue with my previous installation of Ubuntu 16 (Unity) but I noticed that if I turn on my laptop and immediately close the lid then the system will turn off the laptop's screen and act as if the external monitor was the only monitor. This meant I could see the log-in screen and type in the password and life was okay.

I upgraded to Ubuntu Mate 20.04. I could no longer immediately close the lid and still see the log-in prompt on the external monitor. I could just close the lid and wait for the Mate logo to pop up and type in the password (no asterisk feedback), hit enter and be logged in. This was annoying but I understand it was done due to security (whatever, okay).

Now somehow instead of the mate logo, after the computer is ready for me to type in the password, the screen shows the boot time Dell logo again. This is confusing because I have to guess exactly when the Dell logo is just being flashed or we are at a point when I can enter the password and hit enter. I just wait till the Dell logo has been there for a moment after seeing the grey mate load screen (post boot) and type in the password, hit enter to log in.

Adding insult to injury, whenever lid is closed and the external monitor is working and I take off the charger, the laptop suspends. I have seen posts saying just change the lid closed behaviour to do nothing but that is not a solution now is it. I do want the laptop to suspend when I close the lid, JUST not when it's connected to an external display device.

Does anyone know of a way to solve these issues? If nothing else, I'd at least want to know why the Dell logo is shown instead of the log-in window or mate logo once we are ready for the password.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1232480/739431

Comment: concentrate on "vendor logo" text in this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1236448/739431

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. My issue is **not** getting the wrong log-in screen but getting the dell logo instead. And, this only happens when I am attached to an external monitor.

Comment: Changes were made for OEMs, so the brand of the OEM will show through in 20.04 & later releases as part of the `plymouth` screen.  The primary purpose is newer hardware, on older hardware this can cause less than ideal results, but the results are determined by the firmware of the machine itself, and not the code (ie. boot the same ISO on varying devices, and results differ by make/model and most importantly firmware). Due to firmware having such as key role, unless your machine is really modern, you'll likely need to match boot to your exact machine.  (lp. would be place I'd look for detail)