# How to get started on making boot time look like raspberry pi OS?

Tags: boot, login-screen

I have some knowledge of what happens from when I hit the power button till I am presented with the log in screen. I use the Ubuntu Mate 20.04. I have been experiencing inconsistent screens and then different behaviours till the log in screen. I have an open [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1259718/1021500) about that.

In the mean time, I was playing around with my raspberry pi 4 and installed the
Raspberry Pi OS Lite on it. I liked the bare boot-up showing all terminal like things it does before prompting for log in.

If I wanted my Dell machine to boot up like that and be prompted for a password, what things should I do or look into?

I want the boot-up to be like pi before I get to my desktop environment.

Then once I have a better grasp, I am interested in making my own plain text log in screen.

Any help?

Comment: This reads like a duplicate of your listed post.  (*I commented there*)  You've provided little useful detail with regards the non-Ubuntu OS (eg. it's using a different DE, different DM and different `plymouth` though `plymouth` on 20.04 has been changed for most to better suit OEMs, the alternate OS you mention won't have done that)... The non-duplicate is also unclear, at least to me.

Comment: That asks to fix a different problem, here I am simply asking how to get rid of different "splash" screens and instead show what is being done like the raspberry pi OS lite does. Have you ever seen a pi boot-up?

Comment: Yes. but there are many pi images and it's just `nosplash` for version 7 or 8 as I recall (the version that shipped with a r.pi.2b+ so it'll be older than you no doubt mean), ie. no `plymouth` - but it no doubt varies on version.  ie. hit <E> to edit your 20.04 boot in grub, remove the `quiet` and any references to `splash` on the kernel line.  If it's changed since then, adjust accordingly... When you're happy, make changes permanent.